# Including GMP into a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

Could someone tell me how to include the GMP(The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library) libraries into a Qt Project. I followed this guys [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wl0bn1EXPls) (even if i don't know french) on installing GMP properly I guess, but he's using the library in CodeBlocks,and I need it in Qt. I didn't find any helpful information on the internet .

I tried to add the library using the "add library" option on my Qt Project but I guess I failed,because trying to `#include < gmp.h >`  failed also. Any help?

Thank you!

Using: Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that INCLUDEPATH and LIBS are correct in project file:

INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/GMP/includes
LIBS += -L/path/to/GMP/libs -lGMP_library_name_without_prefix_and_extension

Comment: Content of my .pro file: `INCLUDEPATH += /C:/gmp/.libs
LIBS += -L/C:/gmp/.libs - libgmp`   . Still not working. Including `#include <gmp.h>` gives me the following error: **"gmp.h: no such file or directory".**

Comment: changed it as follows:  `INCLUDEPATH += /C:/gmp/.libs LIBS += -L/C:/gmp/.libs - lgmp` still not working

Comment: Try without first slash. LIBS should be on new line. And looks like specified path to headers is wrong.

    INCLUDEPATH += C:/gmp/.libs

    LIBS += -LC:/gmp/.libs -gmp

Comment: I succeeded! It turned out that I didn't install properly GMP (sorry for that). I used [this link](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2013-July/005384.html) to install it properly.After that I followed your instructions. In my .pro file I now have somthing like this: `LIBS += -LC:/gmp/lib/ -lgmp   INCLUDEPATH += C:/gmp/include
  DEPENDPATH += C:/gmp/include` .Each on new line.   _Thank you very much!_